# Math calculations in MySql WHERE

Tags: mysql

Can math calculations be done in the WHERE portion of a MySQL statement?

For example, lets say I have the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT
   employee_id,
   max_hours,
   sum(hours) AS total_hours
FROM
   some_table
WHERE
   total_hours < (max_hours * 1.5)
```

I looked around and found that MySQL does have math functions, but all the examples are in the SELECT portion of the statement.

Comment: Short answer : yes, but it will be slow. MySQL won't use any index for that.

Comment: Run it and see for yourself.

Comment: Kevin - I should have put in that this is psuedo code. The statement I need to do this with is quite complex and would require several hours of coding just to test if this is possible.

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie Can you elaborate a little on what you mean by 'won't use any index'?

Comment: @LeeLoftiss when you do for example WHERE employee_id > 1000, MySQL already know how to find them, he doesn't have to compare each row one by one. When you create a "virtual" column if I can call it like that (your calculation), MySQL doesn't have any index already done, so it will compare each row one by one, can be very slow if you have millions...

Comment: Yes you can perform math calculation in mysql query. check this out. http://www.geeksengine.com/database/basic-select/arithmetic-operations.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any (supported) arithmetic you like in a where or join clause, as long as the final result is a boolean (true, false or NULL (where null is treat as false).

This will usually mean indexes can not be used as their structure only allows their use for direct equality, inequality, or range lookups. In the example you gave there will be no useful index you could define so the query runner would be forced to perform a table scan. For simple filtering clauses referring to one table an index will only get used if one side is a constant (or a variable that is constant for the run time of the query).

With joining clauses an index might be used for one side of the match, if that side is a direct column reference (i.e. no arithmetic) though if the join is likely to cover many rows a scan may still be used as in index (or even table) scan can be quicker than a great many index seeks.

Comment: Thanks David Spillett and jerdiggity.

Answer (score 1):

You might try something like this...

```
SELECT
   employee_id,
   max_hours,
   SUM(hours)
FROM
   some_table
GROUP BY
   employee_id
HAVING
   SUM(hours) < (max_hours * 1.5)
```